# Ignore .DS_Store and Icon files in a folder with Cocoa NSFIleManager

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parsing, icons, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to remove specific files from a directory using NSFileManager. I would like to ignore the hidden .DS_Store and Icon files (the folder that I'm checking has to have a custom icon) that are in the directory, however I keep accidentally deleting them as well. Right now, I'm doing the following:

```
 NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSArray *dirContents = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[selectedFolder stringValue] error:nil]; 
 for (int i = 0; i < [dirContents count]; i++)
 {
     NSString *theFile = [dirContents objectAtIndex:i];

     if([theFile isEqualToString:@".DS_Store"] || [theFile isEqualToString:@"Icon?"] || [theFile isEqualToString:@"Icon"])
     { 
        continue;
     }
     //do manipulations on files here
 }
[manager release];
```

However, the .DS_Store and Icon files aren't being matched in my if statement. Additionally, when I show hidden files in Finder, the icon file is called "Icon". However, doing an ls in that directory in terminal prints out "Icon?".

How can properly I parse these files out in my code?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
So it actually is successfully ignoring the .DS_Store file, but the Icon file is still getting past the if statement.

Comment: If you write `NSLog(@"%@", theFile);` right after setting `theFile`, do those icon file names show up exactly like you’re testing in that `if`?

Comment: +1 Bavarious. It's a good bet that the `?` that you see in Terminal is not actually an ASCII `?`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Interestingly, I believe that the *question* part of [another question posted recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835179/why-is-nsdirectoryenumerator-picking-up-hidden-files-here/5837923#5837923) essentially answers yours. If you use:

```
-[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:]
```

([doc link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:)), you can pass an option, `NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles`, to ignore hidden files so that you don't have to check for specific ones:

```
NSURL * selectedFolderURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[selectedFolder stringValue]];
[myFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:selectedFolderURL
             includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLNameKey]
                                options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                  error:&error];
```

Note that this returns absolute URLs, whereas the method in your question returns paths that are *relative* to the original directory. Easily worked around, but important to know especially if you're deleting stuff.

Comment: This method returns file URLs instead of file paths, so it requires additional modifications to the code.

Comment: `[theURL path]` seemed a little too obvious to have to mention.

Comment: I know ;) In any case, using URLs instead of paths seems to be the more modern, recommended way these days.

Comment: Quite right in my opinion; the path-based API is more limited in certain places.

Comment: URLs are definitely more powerful. But what I wanted to remark is, beside the change from NSString to NSURL, the old method returns an array of filenames relative to the directory path; the new one returns full (absolute) URLs. That bit me until I found out.

Answer (score 3):

The filename of a folder's custom icon resource is "`Icon\r`" (`Icon`, followed by a carriage return).

What I generally do when enumerating a directory in which I want to skip invisible items (those whose name starts with a "."), is to check for a prefix of @".":

```
NSMutableArray *fullPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];

NSArray *subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:filePath];

for (NSString *subpath in subpaths) {
   if ( ![[subpath lastPathComponent] hasPrefix:@"."] && 
        ![[subpath lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"Icon\r"]) {
        [fullPaths addObject:[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:subpath]];
   }
}
// continue
```

The above code will work in 10.5 and later, (or even 10.0, I believe, if you changed the fast enumeration to use an `NSEnumerator`).

P.S. If you are creating your `NSFileManager` using `+defaultManager`, then you shouldn't use the `[manager release]` line, as that would be over-releasing.

So, instead of:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
// 
[manager release];
```

do

```
NSFileManager *manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
//
[manager release];
```

or

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
//
```

Comment: This is unnecessary and possibly dangerous for what the OP was asking. First, `subPathsAtPath:` (whose usage is [not recommended after 10.4](http://goo.gl/RPNfN) (see "Special Considerations")) recurses on subdirectories, which means this may yield files that are _not_ in the original directory. Moreover, `NSFileManager` will skip invisible files _for_ you with `NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles`, and can give you an enumerator over the directory contents with `enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:` if that's what you want (although, N.B., that also recurses).

Comment: One remark: not every hidden file has a name that starts with `.`, e.g. `SetFile -a V /path/to/file`.

Answer (score -1):

Simple method:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *imageFilenames = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [imageFilenames count]; i++)
    {

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,[imageFilenames objectAtIndex:i] ];

        if (![[imageFilenames objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@".DS_Store"])
        {
          UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
          UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_myimage];
        }
    }
```