# How to remove .DS_Store from NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have a code to get objects out of the path @"/Users/playra/Desktop/2 DivyaLoka/Собрание Тайн"

```
- (void) setPathProperty:(NSString *)pathProperty
{
    _pathProperty = pathProperty;
    NSArray* allContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathProperty error:nil];
    self.contents = allContents;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.navigationItem.title = [self.pathProperty lastPathComponent];
}
```

Below in this line comes object .DS_Store

```
NSArray* allContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathProperty error:nil];
```

How to remove it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
NSMutableArray * dirContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:docDir];
if([docDir containsObject:@".DS_Store"])
{
    [dirContents removeObject:@".DS_Store"];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `removeObject:` will remove matching strings or only the specific object instance (i.e. the string constant `@".DS_Store"`)?

Comment: yeah it'll remove from array

Comment: +1 but note that the check for `containsObject` isn't needed.

Comment: @Mayur It helped me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851164/ignore-ds-store-and-icon-files-in-a-folder-with-cocoa-nsfilemanager

NSMutableArray *fullPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];

NSArray *subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:filePath];

for (NSString *subpath in subpaths) {
   if ( ![[subpath lastPathComponent] hasPrefix:@"."] && 
        ![[subpath lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"Icon\r"]) {
        [fullPaths addObject:[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:subpath]];
   }
}
// continue

Comment: @setoffonom ok great enjoy :)