# How to skip hidden files/folders using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, directory, hidden-files

I want to find all markdown files within the user's home directory. The solution has to be very efficient, because this folder contains mostly a great heap of different files.

How to skip hidden files/folders by using a `NSDirectoryEnumarator`? I only found a [solution by using URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835179/why-is-nsdirectoryenumerator-picking-up-hidden-files-here) and not string-paths.

```c
NSString *path = NSHomeDirectory();
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:path];

//some type of filter

NSString *file;

while (file=[directoryEnum nextObject]){

    if([file hasSuffix:@".md"]){
        //yes it's markdown
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not convert the path to a URL before enumerating?

Comment: You link to the solution in your question...