# Skip hidden subfolders with NSDirectoryEnumerator

Tags: objective-c, extract

Is there any chance to skip the hidden subfoldres using NSDirectoryEnumerator?

My code looks as the following:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
NSString *file = nil;
NSDirectoryEnumerator* fileEnumerator=[manager enumeratorAtPath: pathName]; 
while ((file= [fileEnumerator nextObject])){
    if ([self.smetadataExtraction filterByextension:file]){
        ....
    } 
}
```

I know there is a chance to can skip the hidden subfolders using instead of enumeratorAtPath, enumeratorAtURL. Like in the following example:

[Why is NSDirectoryEnumerator picking up hidden files here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835179/why-is-nsdirectoryenumerator-picking-up-hidden-files-here)

But is there any chance of doing it using enumeratorAtPath?

Comment: Why not convert to a URL before enumerating?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip hidden files folders using ObjC?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21673280)

Comment: I know I could do it that way but it's senseless and I want to know if it's possible to do it with path

Comment: Not senseless, entirely sensible...